# Change Background Color HTML Page

Tags: html, colors, background

I am using a simple HTML page with a few tables in it, and I want to change the background color of the page. When I try changing the bgcolor it only changes a little thin line at the very bottom of the page where it says footer text here, rather than the background color. I don't want to change the color of the tables but just the color behind so that the outer edges of the page have the background color and the centre has a white table with content.

Here is a draft of the code from the table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-gb">
<title>Your Title Here</title>

<style>
LI.MsoNormal {
FONT-SIZE: 12pt; FONT-FAMILY: "Times New Roman"; mso-style-parent: ""; margin-    left:0in; margin-right:0in; margin-top:0in; margin-bottom:0pt
}
.H1 {
FONT-SIZE: 36px; : #d70305
}
H1 {
FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}
H2 {
FONT-SIZE: 20px; COLOR: #000000
}
H2 {
FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}
.style22 {font-size: 12px}
.style13 {font-family: Tahoma;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
}
.style16 { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 24pt;
color: #000000;
font-weight: bold;
}
.style17 {color: #993300}
.style3 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
}
.style4 {color: #666633;
font-size: 12px;
}
.style6 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; }
.style90 {font-size: 18pt}
.headline1 {
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 24pt;
font-weight: bold;
color: #C00;
}
</style>

</head>
<body leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" bgcolor="#242424">
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td align="center" background="images/top.jpg">
<img src="images/header.jpg" width="873" height="233"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="background-image:url(images/middle.jpg); background-repeat:repeat-x;    background-color:#ffffff">
<table width="859" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  background="images/sides.jpg">
<tr>
<td><table width="780" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<div align="center">


<!--Table Content here-->

</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</table>             
</td>
<tr>
<td align="center" background="images/bottom.jpg">
<img src="images/footer.jpg" width="873" height="126"></td></tr>
</table>
<font color="#999999" size="2" face="Tahoma">footer text here</font></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Warning: Your Doctype triggers [Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) in which browsers emulate bugs in old browsers, don't support some features, and are significantly less consistent with each other. You should avoid it.

Comment: You could improve your code by keeping all style in your CSS, and not using HTML attributes like `border`, `topmargin`, etc. directly in your HTML. This way you can easier maintain the site and find the right spot for such adaptions faster.

Comment: Your Doctype is set to HTML 4 and you are using <style> without the type="text/css" attribute, which you should do.

Comment: Code worked fine for me. I guess your table is taking over your whole page. Give a definite size or use smaller tables to see the change.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use inline styles as it's deprecated
First way is you can use style attribute on body tag.

```
<body style="background-color:#242424;margin-top:0px;margin-left:0px;">
```

Second way is to define styles in internal style tag -

```
<style>
   body{
      background-color:#242424;
      margin-top:0px;
      margin-left:0px;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: @Quentin - What doctype should I use?

Comment: When I change this line to less than 100%:

<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

I see the background appearing and this outer table getting smaller, but it won't get any less smaller than about 5mm either side of the main table. I don't even know what this other table is for really but I tried commenting it out and the top section and bottom footer left-aligned.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you to change the background color

```
<style>
    body
    {
        background:#000;// This will give black background color to your entire body
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

To change just the color of the background of a page In HTML, There are lots of ways but I have noticed it is hard to find the simplest version which requires basic HTML, and not CSS or JS or any other language/API or anything.
Here is the code below, feel free to copy paste it-
+

```
<body bgcolor="whatever color you want to put">
```

Answer (score 0):

add this css

```
<style>
body
{
    background:#009;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I have noticed that the background color in one of my other pages changed to what I want but there seems to be another background underneath the main table, and I can see on the right hand side of the page, from bottom to top, a little slit line of background color.

I tried changing sizes in both table widths but it only changed width of the table and then the text in the table. There ssems to be something between the background and the table that I can't alter.

I did not originally build this page - I can edit and play about with HTML only not fault find more complex (to me) problems.

Comment: what do I do with this style? Where/how do I use it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this css

```
<style>       
  body  
  {  
      background-color:#as45er;  
  }    
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

if your using just html without css/scss then you can use bgcolor in body tag 
Example  or 
and if your using css or scss
then 
body{
      background-color: "black";
         or
       background-color: #000000;
this will help you thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format the code snippets in your answer with ``.

Answer (score 0):

You can change background color of a html page by using css in your html code.

Option 1 : `style="background-color: #yourcolor";`

Option 2 : `.body { background-color: #yourcolor; }`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this use this "*" without any div name.

```css
* {
background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Option-1:style="background-color: #yourcolor";

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).