# How to add background color

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I was trying to add like a blue background to code below but I wasn’t sure on how to do it:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

<title>Success Page</title>

<style>
h1 {
  font-size: 2cm;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  font-size: 1cm;
  padding: 20px;
}
</style>


</head>


 <div class="container">
 <h1>Sucess Page</h1>
<p>Congratulations your            registration was successful!!!</p>
<a href="index.html"><button   class="btn btn--pill btn--green" type="submit">OK</button>
</a>


</div>

</body>

</html>`
```

I tried searching and asking some friends no one was that much of a help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Background Color HTML Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739506/change-background-color-html-page)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  "*I tried searching*" - what was wrong with the results you found?  There are so many, for so many different circumsances, we have to assume you saw them and they didn't help - why not?  Your code does not include anything related to bg colour, what did you try that failed? https://stackoverflow.com/q/9648910/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/25329260/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/72062214/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/72539177/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/47914130/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/36815858/6089612 ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to set the background color of the whole page in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648910/how-to-set-the-background-color-of-the-whole-page-in-css)

Answer (score 1):

If you need entire page in blue color

```
body {
   background-color: blue;
}
```